# Creating a Pie Chart using PHP to create json

Tags: php, json, laravel, charts, highcharts

I am attempting to create a pie chart in an application (Laravel MVC) by creating the array structure in PHP then when it is passed to the view using json_encode to make it compatible but my pie chart is all jacked up.

My dataset

```
gender | total
Female | 20
Male | 17
Other | 3
```

I have this:

```
$chartArray["chart"] = array("plotBackgroundColor" => "null", "plotBorderWidth" => "null", "plotShadow" => "false");
        $chartArray["title"] = array("text" => "Pet Intakes By Gender");
        $chartArray["tooltip"] = array("pointFormat" => "{series.name}: {point.percentage:.1f}%");
        $chartArray['plotOptions'] = array("pie" => array("allowPointSelect"=>"true","cursor"=>"pointer","dataLabels"=>array("enabled" => "false"),"showInLegend" => "true"));
$data = [];
foreach($results as $result){
$data = $this->array_push_assoc($data, $result->gender, $result->total);
}
$chartArray["series"] = array(array("type" => 'pie', "name" => 'Percentage of Gender', "data" =>array($data)));

return $chartArray;
```

which produces this when encoded:

```
{
   "chart":{
      "plotBackgroundColor":"null",
      "plotBorderWidth":"null",
      "plotShadow":"false"
   },
   "title":{
      "text":"Pet Intakes By Gender"
   },
   "tooltip":{
      "pointFormat":"{series.name}: {point.percentage:.1f}%"
   },
   "plotOptions":{
      "pie":{
         "allowPointSelect":"true",
         "cursor":"pointer",
         "dataLabels":{
            "enabled":"false"
         },
         "showInLegend":"true"
      }
   },
   "series":[
      {
         "type":"pie",
         "name":"Percentage of Gender",
         "data":[
            {
               "Female":17,
               "Male":12,
               "Other":2
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

And I need to get to something like this (from the site example):

```
{
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    ['Firefox',   45.0],
                    ['IE',       26.8],
                    {
                        name: 'Chrome',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Safari',    8.5],
                    ['Opera',     6.2],
                    ['Others',   0.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: And this isn't working... how?

Comment: The chart area is black, there are just thin lines stacked on top of each other (or maybe just 1 line) and the legend says slice http://beta.petpalmanager.com/files/pie.png

Answer (score 0):

Your data format is wrong:

```
     "data":[
        {
           "Female":17,
           "Male":12,
           "Other":2
        }
     ]
```

That means you have only one slice, without any value..

I guess this is what you want to do:

```
     "data":[
        ["Female", 17],
        ["Male", 12],
        ["Other", 2]
     ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas on how to modify the script I posted to get that result?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not PHP dev.